# Battery on Ubuntu 12.10 is less compared to win7!

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, power-management, battery

I installed ubuntu 12.10 alongside win7 ultimate on my lenovo ultrabook U410, but the problem is I get 6 hours with win7 while only 3.30 hours on Ubuntu. I installed PowerTop but It does not provide any guide to kill the processes(by pressing various keys)!!
It just gives the insight of processes..nothin more..!!
I also installed laptopMode, set the enable laptop mode=1 but still i m stuck..!!
Plz Guide... 
thnks..

Comment: does your laptop have NVIDIA optimus card? there are several U410 models

Answer (score 1):

I would give the jupiter applet a shot. I am using a toshiba satellite with a 65kwh battery, and I can average about 10 hours on a single charge, running in "power saving" mode (via the applet), and about 8 hours while using the "power on demand" mode.

To install, ope the terminal and type in:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/jupiter
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jupiter
```