# Ubuntu 12.10 Battery monitor problem?

Tags: 12.10, battery

With win7 I had about 4hrs battery life. My battery was fully charged and I had my laptop plugged in during the entire install of ubuntu. However, about 15 minutes after unplugging my laptop I get a message that says I only have 19 minutes of battery left. So now instead of 4 hours of battery I only have 45 minutes max. WTF?

Everything I've researched so far seems to say things like "change your power settings" "dim your screen" etc. But none of these 'solutions' would in anyway account for a missing 3 hours of battery life.

So is this an issue with the battery monitor itself? How do I fix this? I came to Ubuntu because I'm starting to learn some programming and my win7 was gettting too buggy. I really don't want to go back now that I've seen what ubuntu is, but I can't function with only a half hour battery that I KNOW will last at least 3 hours. Please help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Battery on Ubuntu 12.10 is less compared to win7!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/210402/battery-on-ubuntu-12-10-is-less-compared-to-win7)

Comment: You can also install powertop which is a Linux tool to find out what is using power on a laptop. you can get it here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/powertop .I advise you to check out this link on Power Saving Tweaks. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/PowerSavingTweaks

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that post. They have a lenovo something or other. Also, while the problem is similar, I don't have an nvidia card I just have an integrated chipset. This laptop isn't super awesome, but it usually gets the job done.

Again my problem, from what little I know, isn't an issue of power consumption.My intuition tells me its something wrong with the battery monitor of my ubuntu or something similar. 
While I can understand a new OS using slightly more or less battery, power consumption certainly couldn't be so different as to reduce my battery life by 150% or more

Comment: I'm trying to use powertop now, and maybe there is just something i"m missing, but I ran it using:
sudo powertop
then entered my password, but no gui started.. the program seems to just be running in the terminal. 
Also, I was just reading [http://askubuntu.com/questions/172391/is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels] (is-laptop-mode-tools-still-relevant-for-12-04-and-the-3-x-kernels), and in it one person responded that Ubuntu is already using most of the powersaving features powertop would provide.
SO still stuck with a 30min battery and am no closer to an answer.

Comment: I don't think anyone is even looking at this anymore, but I followed the ubuntu wiki article and enabled the i915 bit by editing some 'grub' file. But according to powertop it still is interrupting between 15% and 20% of the time so it would seem this didn't do anything? 
Also, installed laptop mode tools but haven't had the chance to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after lots of research from multiple websites and hours of reading (and no help from this post):
Here is what I used to increase my battery life from 45min to 2:15 fully charged.
Installed the following programs
Powertop
Laptop Mode Tools
Jupiter

I then figured out how to enable Intel i915 RC6 by using the following commands:

```
gksudo nautilus
```

which enabled me to have root access to the `/etc/default/grub` file 
that I then modified the following lines

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.i915_enable_rc6=1"
```

and then used the terminal command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Next I uninstalled all programs I was not using or would not use (including all the default media applications which I replaced with VLC) especially anything related to "bluetooth" as I have no bluetooth devices.

I also made sure that beagle and updatedb are disabled such that they won't consume unnecessary power.

I managed to do all of this after literally hours of reading about how to properly use the terminal, multitudes of google searches, and a composition notebook now half filled with terminal commands and lists of apps.

Ultimately I feel as though powertop, laptop mode tools, and jupiter are all basically doing the same thing from different angles and should all just be things that Ubuntu already should have, but that would just be crazy wouldn't it?